# Dropping element at exact position using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have made an UI where i have created a div inside which multiple divs or slots(say).These slots are generated using Knockout.js,I mean these slot are binded on slider value.Depending on the value of the slider it generate the slots dynamically.My concern is that i want to Drop the other outside element on these divs but when i am doing this it is getting droped on the last div and again if i drop it again added to the upper div of the Slot.bt i want that it must be dropped where i am dropping it i.e on the same position.it can be at midway of two div as well.please suggest me.My code is as follows:

```
<div class="slotSystem">
                        <div class="slotMachine" data-bind="foreach:slots,style:{height:height()+'px'}">
                            <div class="slot">
                                <div class="slot-info drop" data-bind="text:formatedTime,style:{height:height()+'px'}"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
$(".drop").droppable({
            accept: ".draggable",
            tolerance:"pointer",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                console.log("drop");
                var dropped = ui.draggable;
                var droppedOn = $(this);
                $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(droppedOn);

                $('#clear-organizer').show();
                $('#saveplaylist').show();
                $(dropped).height(10);

                var closebtn = ui.draggable.find(' .close');
                $(closebtn).addClass('close-organizer');


            }
        });
```

Comment: You should really formulate your post as a clear **question** to maximize your changes of getting an answer, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you told it to do in your code. To make it do what you write in your question, you just want to make the `.slotMachine` DIV the droppable one, not the `.slot-info` (or even `.slot` for that matter).

EDIT: If you want to find out on what DIV you dropped on and place the dragged DIV next to it, leave `.slot`s droppable and in your drop handler use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter) or [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) (which inserts your element **outside** of the `droppedOn` target) instead of `.appendTo()` you are using now (which would insert your element **inside** the `droppedOn` target).

Comment: I have gone through this also. But as you told in this answer, It wont Append the dropped DIV in between two different DIV with classname="slot".

Comment: Ah, OK, then make the slots droppable and instead of `.appendTo(droppedOn)` use either `.insertBefore(droppedOn)` or `.insertAfter(droppedOn)`.

Comment: not working..i need this dropable element must be in between two divs which are joined with each others using border of 1px and means it must be shared between two divs as specified.

Comment: Of course it works. See http://jsfiddle.net/r3WAU/ You need to insert before `droppedOn`'s parent.